# INotifyDataErrorInfo is ignored when opening a window with an user control a second time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifydataerrorinfo

I've got quite a confusing situation:

I open a dialogue that shows a view with an `INotifyDataErrorInfo` that immediately returns an error (when the text field is not empty), I see the the red border error notifier:

Opening #1:

[image: First opening]

I do nothing and close the window, then click the open button again:

Opening #2:

[image: Second opening]

What the heck? I've checked the error flag, it is set. The error border re-appears when I remove the text and write something back, since the error condition checks for `string empty? error: no error`

Here is a small reproduction case:

**Edit: I added the ViewModel back, which is created on every show, causing the INCP change event**

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace LayoutBreakerMinimal
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            var w = new Window();
            var v = Resources["OneInstanceView"] as View; // new View(); <-- would work
            w.Content = v;
            v.DataContext = new ViewModel();
            w.ShowDialog();
        }
    }


    public partial class View : UserControl
    {
        public View()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }


    public partial class ViewModel : INotifyDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _myTextField;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            MyTextField = "Error field";
        }

        public string MyTextField
        {
            get { return _myTextField; }
            set
            {
                _myTextField = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                if ( ErrorsChanged != null ) ErrorsChanged( this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs( "MyTextField" ) );
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable GetErrors( string propertyName )
        {
            yield return "Field is null";
        }

        public bool HasErrors
        {
            get { return MyTextField != ""; }
        }

        public event EventHandler< DataErrorsChangedEventArgs > ErrorsChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null )
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if ( handler != null ) handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="LayoutBreakerMinimal.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:layoutBreakerMinimal="clr-namespace:LayoutBreakerMinimal"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <layoutBreakerMinimal:View x:Key="OneInstanceView" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Margin="40">Open Dialog, then open it again</Button>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

View.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="LayoutBreakerMinimal.View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
 <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyTextField, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Height="30" Width="100"></TextBox>
    <Label Content="{Binding HasErrors}" Height="30" Width="100"></Label>
 </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I can't get my head around why the border vanishes.

What I've found out: If I create the view every time new (and not the single resource instance), then the red border is available right from the start every time.

I tested moving the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` into a separate `ViewModel`, which is instantiated every time new -> No luck.

**Edit 2: I added the HasError label to the View to indicate that it keeps displaying error**

Comment: I would guess It's not needing to re-validate your text if you are just showing the same instance again.  Does it work correctly if you force a NotifyPropertyChanged upon showing the view?

Comment: @TheodosiusVonRichthofen thanks for the hint. I updated my example and added the view model, which gets instantiated on every show. The ctor calls the INPC every time, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Out of curiousity, if you replace your bound string with something different each time it's displayed, do you get the results expected? For example, `v.DataContext = new ViewModel() { MyTextField = DateTime.Now.ToString() };`

Comment: @Rachel, nope. Different time-strings, no red border after first run. I've been researching on how to reset the state of the view. I implemented Dispose of ViewModel, reset `MyTextField` to something that would result in changing `HasErrors` to false before destroying the view model, no effect.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `GetErrors`, how many times does it get called in both the first time and subsequent times? My best guess is it has something to do with the timing of validation vs render... I bet if the Dispatcher was used to set DataContext after it rendered, it would update correctly. But you shouldn't have to do that

Comment: @Rachel: Both times it is called 4 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Add `x:Shared="False"` as shown below: I have tested the fix and it's working as expected.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <layoutBreakerMinimal:View x:Key="OneInstanceView" x:Shared="False" />
</Window.Resources>
```

When `x:Shared="False"`, modifies WPF resource-retrieval behavior so that requests for the attributed resource create a new instance for each request instead of sharing the same instance for all requests.

Here is the Modified **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="LayoutBreakerMinimal.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:layoutBreakerMinimal="clr-namespace:LayoutBreakerMinimal"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <layoutBreakerMinimal:View x:Key="OneInstanceView" x:Shared="False" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Margin="40">Open Dialog, then open it again</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It works, I forgot about x:Shared, thanks for that. This indeed solves my problem even for non trivial views. Although it haunts me, why the validation state is not reset between calls :/

Comment: This is actually not a solution for all scenarios. I use prism's `InteractionRequestTrigger` that references a `TriggerAction` implementation which does not refetch the view every time.